# What is the purpose of Zip -g (MacOs)

Tags: macos, aws-lambda, zip

I am deploying a lambda function using a zip file (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html). I am curious what is the purpose of the "-g" command in
`zip -g my-deployment-package.zip lambda_function.py`

I cannot find any documentation about it.

Comment: If you don't know about `man` command, this is a good time to learn.  Try `man zip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use macOS Terminal "-g" mean grow, it will append and update the files in a existing zip file.
It is nice for debug and reinstall packages.